# Asynchronously calling synchronous I/O using TAP

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a piece of code that must delete a potentially large number of files as efficiently as possible.  I currently have the following function that gets called for each file:

```
private void deleteLocalFile(string Root, string RelativePath)
{
    string FilePath = Path.Combine(Root, RelativePath);
    File.SetAttributes(FilePath, File.GetAttributes(FilePath) & ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
    File.Delete(FilePath);
}
```

I could wrap this with Task.Run(), but I understand that it's best to use that for mainly CPU bound tasks, whereas this example is largely I/O bound.  And I can't find an example of best practices for this type of scenario.

I'd presumably call an asynchronous version of this (supporting both progress and cancellation) as follows:

```
List<Task> DeleteTasks = new List<Task>();
for (string RelativePath in SomeListOfRelativePaths)
{
    DeleteTasks.Add(deleteLocalFileAsync(RootPath, RelativePath, Progress, CancellationToken);
}
Task.WaitAll(DeleteTasks);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your underlying operation is synchronous there's nothing you can do to turn it asynchronous. You need a different asynchronous API, but it doesn't have to necessarily be Task based as you can turn any kind of async API into TAP.

You can offload it to a different thread with `Task.Run` as you pointed out but that isn't more efficient.